# Laravel error : Integrity constraint violation

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

Routes

```php
Route::post('/review','RentalController@review');
```

Controller

```php
public function review(Request $request)
{
    $review = new Reviews();
    $rpId = rand();
    $review->rvid=$rpId;
    $review->usid_fk = Auth::user()->uid;
    // $propId= $request->input('propId');
    $review->prId_fk = $request->input('propId');
    $review->comment = $request->input('comment');
    $review->rating = $request->input('rating');
    $review->date = Carbon::now();
    $review->save();
}
```

Migration File

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('review', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('rvId')->primary();
        $table->integer('usId_fk');
        $table->foreign('usId_fk')->references('uid')->on('users');
        $table->integer('prId_fk');
        $table->foreign('prId_fk')->references('pId')->on('properties');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->integer('rating');
        $table->string('comment');
    });
}
```

View (Blade template)

```php
<form action="{{ url('/review') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="hidden" name="propid" value="{{ $prop->propid }}"/>
        <input id="rating" name="rating" class="rating rating-loading" data-show-clear="false" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="1" value="0">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">Comment</span>
            </div>
            <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" aria-label="Comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the error is  integrity constraint violation error.

> The `prId_fk` cannot be null integrity constraint violation

I have been trying to fix this for a couple of days already. I've been trying to rewrite my code over and over again still it didn't work. Your reply would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: it is because of the column didnt accept null value.. change `$table->integer('prId_fk');` to `$table->integer('prId_fk')->nullable();`

Comment: have you make sure that `propid` not null in html form?

Comment: Your migration contains field "usId_fk" but you are storing attribute "usid_fk". change it. (I capital, not small) -> in the controller

Comment: i updated it to $table->integer('prId_fk')->nullable(); im trying to get the propid and it aers to be null in the table

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the data as `propid` from your form but you are trying to access it as `propId` in your controller. Make sure the cases match.

Either change the input in the form to

```php
<input type="hidden" name="propId" value="{{ $prop->propid }}"/>
```

or update your controller to refer to the right index.

```php
$review->prId_fk = $request->input('propid');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because as per your migration file your `prId_fk` did not accept null values and your hidden inputfile name is `propid` and your accessing it using `propId`

You can set your `prId_fk` to accept null in your migration file as below

```
$table->integer('prId_fk')->nullable();
```

OR

access it correctly

```
$request->input('propid');
```

Comment: i already changed it to make it the ssame but i still get "prId_fk' is null

Comment: pLs share the output of  `$request->input('propId');;`